# Ubuntu Netbook - I can't see panels

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, gnome-panel, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gnome Panels not Visible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33471/gnome-panels-not-visible)

I installed the netbook version on my notebook and now I can't see taskbar or panel. If I switch to the desktop version everything is normal.