# Gnome Panels not Visible

Tags: 10.04, gnome-panel

Sometimes, when logging into my PC, some or all of my Gnome panels fail to appear, so I'm left with a blank screen and no way to log out/shutdown or run any programs. Why haven't the panels appeared? How can I get them back? I can sometimes create a new panel and add a new launcher to it to reboot, but it's a bit of a long winded solution. I'm using the 10.04 LTS release.

Comment: Please add a tag for which version you installed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well  , 
I had script for resetting the gnome panel .
I am not  sure if this script will work on notebook version , i used it in desktop version ,and its very helpful .

save this script to PanelRestore.sh  to the desktop for example and `chmod +x PanelRestore.sh`  and then run it by terminal  `./PanelRestore.sh` , a new window will pop up , just click restore default setting  and you would be good to go

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# GNOME Panel Save / Restore
# Writen by PhrankDaChicken
#
# http://ubuntu.online02.com
#
#
# Updated to add restore defaults by jimjimovich
# http://www.starryhope.com
#
#


DIR=$(pwd)
TITLE="PanelRestore"

Main () {
    CHOICE=$(zenity --list --title "$TITLE" --hide-column 1 --text "What do you want to do?" --column "" --column "" \
"0" "Save Panel Settings" \
"1" "Restore Panel Settings" \
"2" "Restore Default Panel Settings")
    if [ $CHOICE = 0 ]; then
        Panel_Save
    fi
    if [ $CHOICE = 1 ]; then
        Panel_Restore
    fi
    if [ $CHOICE = 2 ]; then
        Panel_Defaults
    fi  
}

Panel_Restore () {
    FILE=$(zenity --title "$TITLE: Open File" --file-selection --file-filter "*.xml" )
    if [ -n "$FILE" ]; then 
        gconftool-2 --load "$FILE"
        killall gnome-panel
    fi
    Main
}

Panel_Save () {
    FILE=$(zenity --title "$TITLE: Save File" --file-selection --save --confirm-overwrite --filename "Gnome_Panel.xml" --file-filter "*.xml" )
    if [ -n "$FILE" ]; then 
        EXT=$(echo "$FILE" | grep "xml")
        if [ "$EXT" = "" ]; then
            FILE="$FILE.xml"
        fi
        gconftool-2 --dump /apps/panel > $FILE
        zenity --info --title "$TITLE: File Saved" --text "File saved as: \n $FILE"
    fi
    Main
}

Panel_Defaults () {
    zenity --question --text="Are you sure you want to restore the default top and bottom panels?"
    gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/panel
    rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
    pkill gnome-panel
    exit
}

Main

# END OF Script
```

Answer (score 1):

try running this command

> > gnome-panel

Check if your panels are restored.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press ALT+F2 and in the run dialog box, type `gnome-terminal`

In the terminal, type

`gconftool-2 — – shutdown` (no space between the dashes and no space between the dash and the word ‘shutdown’)

1. `rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel`
2. `pkill gnome-panel`

Answer (score 0):

You can restart the panels by typing

```
killall gnome-panel
```

Comment: As there are no panels, there's no easy way to get a terminal window. I could Ctrl-Alt-F1 and log in again or create a new launcher item in a new panel and then remove it when things are back to normal, which is sort-of-OK for me but not for the less computer-literate here (my kids - bringing them up without Windows!). I was hoping there was a way to stop them not appearing.

Comment: Well it's not a permanent fix but you could put the above in a file on the desktop - run it if the panels don't appear :)